# Ngrx how to create store with multiple reducers

Tags: angular, ngrx

I couldn't find the docs for this, does anyone know how to modify the NGRX store to accept multiple reducers aka multiple slices of state?

Comment: Donno if i understand the question.. You add more feature like this `StoreModule.forFeature(FEATURE_NAME, REDUCER_CLASS)`. Does this answer the question?